# why js keyframe (cssrules) script won't work with IE edge and it work in chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

why js keyframe (cssrules) script for Seconds Time which will see in codepen link won't work with IE EDGE and it work in chrome and firefox with two different solution with same result in the following links

[Solution 1](https://codepen.io/ockba/pen/OajzyL)

```
function clockRingSecond(angle, key) {
  "use strict";
  var d = document,
      stylesheet = d.styleSheets[0],
      rule = stylesheet.cssRules,
      i = rule.length,
      keyframes,
      keyframe,
      n = "spinRing";
  while (i--) {
    keyframes = rule.item(i);
    if (
      (keyframes.type === keyframes.KEYFRAMES_RULE ||
       keyframes.type === keyframes.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE ||
       keyframes.type === keyframes.MOZ_KEYFRAMES_RULE ||
       keyframes.type === keyframes.MS_KEYFRAMES_RULE ||
       keyframes.type === keyframes.O_KEYFRAMES_RULE) &&
      keyframes.name === n
    ) {
      rule = keyframes.cssRules;
      i = rule.length;
      while (i--) {
        keyframe = rule.item(i);
        if (
          (keyframe.type === keyframe.KEYFRAME_RULE ||
           keyframe.type === keyframe.WEBKIT_KEYFRAME_RULE ||
           keyframe.type === keyframe.MS_KEYFRAME_RULE) &&
          keyframe.keyText === key
        ) {
          keyframe.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
          keyframe.style.msTransform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
          keyframe.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
secondTimeHand();
```

and

[Solution 2](https://codepen.io/ockba/pen/MzvrBr)

```
function seckey(ruleText) {
  var sheets = document.styleSheets;
  if (sheets.length == 0) {
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
    document.head.appendChild(style);
  }
  var sheet = sheets[sheets.length - 1];
  sheet.insertRule(
    ruleText,
    sheet.rules ? sheet.rules.length : sheet.cssRules.length
  );
}
secondTimeHand();
```

This two solution I found it in some post here.

Please help and thank you in advance

Please Note that it works with before and now it stop

Comment: Please Note that it works with before and now it stop

Comment: I gues its because first pen has support prefix for css animation in microsoft browsers `-ms-animation`. Take a look what vendor prefixes is https://www.lifewire.com/css-vendor-prefixes-3466867

Comment: Thank you but I already add the all prefixes with same Problem